# knockout kendo "kendoMaskedTextBox" not working

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui

I am using "knockout-kendo 0.8.1" and trying to implement `kendoMaskedTextBox`.
I am not able get `kendoMaskedTextBox` object value, I get `undefined` when debugging, like for below code

```
$("kendoMaskedTextBox").kendoMaskedTextBox({
    mask: "(000) 000-0000"
});
```

In above code `$("kendoMaskedTextBox").kendoMaskedTextBox` is `undefined`.

For other knockout-kendo controls I am able to get object value, like

```
$("startDate").kendoDatePicker({

});
```

How I can I to proceed to work with kendoMaskedTextBox ?

Comment: Are you missing a `#` in `$("kendoMaskedTextBox")`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are missing a `#` and it should be

```
$("#kendoMaskedTextBox").data("kendoMaskedTextBox")
```

Apparently you init with

```
$("#maskedtextbox").kendoMaskedTextBox({
    mask: "(999) 000-0000"
});
```

And get the value with

```
var maskedtextbox = $("#maskedtextbox").data("kendoMaskedTextBox");

var setValue = function () {
    maskedtextbox.value($("#value").val());
};
```

See [here for example](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/maskedtextbox/api)